# lein compile target-path configuration

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I need some help with lein.

I need to compile my program to **build/classes/main/**

Lein append /classes to whatever folder I specify at project.clj :target-path.

For example, if I set:

```
:target-path "build"
```

files will be generated at **build/classes** instead of build/classes/main

If I set:

```
:target-path "build/classes/main"
```

files will be generated at **build/classes/main/classes**

**build/classes/main/** is where my grails project compile all Groovy and Java classes before packaging the war file. My Clojure .class must be there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project.clj set `:compile-path`

```
:target-path "build"
:compile-path "%s/classes/main"
```